# Referring generic typescript function component in styled-components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I've created a generic component to render a DataGrid like this:

```
interface Props<T extends unknown> {
    header: HeaderItem[]
    data?: T[],
    className?: string,
    children?: (row: T) => React.ReactElement[]
}

const DataGrid = <T extends unknown>({ header, data, className, children }: Props<T>): React.ReactElement | null => {
   ...
}
```

Because of the generic type it's not possible to set `React.FC<Props<T>>` as type for `DataGrid` (or at least I haven't found a solution.
Now I'm trying to set some additional styles inside another component using styled-components.

```
const Container = styled.div`
    ${DataGrid} {

    }
`
```

By using this the build fails with a wall of an error saying "No overload matches this call"

```
TypeScript error in ...:
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(first: TemplateStringsArray | CSSObject | InterpolationFunction<ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "slot" | ... 253 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & ColumnProps, any>>, ...rest: Interpolation<...>[]): StyledComponent<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '<T extends unknown>({ header, data, className, children }: Props<T>) => React.ReactElement | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Interpolation<ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "slot" | "style" | "title" | ... 251 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & ColumnProps, any>>'.
      Type '<T extends unknown>({ header, data, className, children }: Props<T>) => React.ReactElement | null' is not assignable to type 'InterpolationFunction<ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "slot" | "style" | "title" | ... 251 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & ColumnProps, any>>'.
        Types of parameters '__0' and 'props' are incompatible.
          Property 'header' is missing in type 'Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "slot" | "style" | "title" | ... 251 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & ColumnProps & ThemeProps<...>' but required in type 'Props<unknown>'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(first: TemplateStringsArray | CSSObject | InterpolationFunction<ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "slot" | ... 253 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & ColumnProps & Props<...>, any>>, ...rest: Interpolation<...>[]): StyledComponent<...>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '<T extends unknown>({ header, data, className, children }: Props<T>) => React.ReactElement | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Interpolation<ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "slot" | "style" | "title" | ... 251 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & ColumnProps & Props<...>, any>>'.
      Type '<T extends unknown>({ header, data, className, children }: Props<T>) => React.ReactElement | null' is not assignable to type 'InterpolationFunction<ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "slot" | "style" | "title" | ... 251 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & ColumnProps & Props<...>, any>>'.
        Type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null' is not assignable to type 'Interpolation<ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "slot" | "style" | "title" | ... 251 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & ColumnProps & Props<...>, any>>'.
          Type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>' is not assignable to type 'Interpolation<ThemedStyledProps<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>, HTMLDivElement>, "slot" | "style" | "title" | ... 251 more ... | "onTransitionEndCapture"> & { ...; } & ColumnProps & Props<...>, any>>'.
            Type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>' is not assignable to type 'CSSObject'.
              Index signature is missing in type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>'.  TS2769
```

It's all working when I remove the generic. Is there a way to use the referenced styling with a generic?

Comment: it would help if you could create a working sandbox, I'm not sure I get the question 100%

Answer (score 0):

Well one thing I can see in the example is that you are trying to extend the style of a non-styled-component. your `DataGrid` has to be defined as a styled-component before you can do this:

```js
const Container = styled.div`
    ${DataGrid} {...}
`
```

So you would have to either extend the styled component inside `DataGrid` or convert `DataGrid` to a styled-component:

```js
const StyledDataGrid = styled(DataGrid)``;
```